# Associate AIR app in OSX without breaking codesigning

Tags: macos, air, installation

If an app is build in Flash/AIR and exported as Captive Runtime for OSX, how does one associate a filetype with that app without breaking codesigning?

In a more general sense, can one edit the Info.plist in any app without invalidating codesigning, or use some other signed installer to handle the associations (like one would do on windows) and then sign that?

The only way I've seen to associate the app with a filetype, so far, is via the guide at https://superuser.com/questions/178316/how-to-set-an-icon-for-a-file-type-on-mac

This, according to the comments there, does invalidate codesigning.

Answer (score 0):

If an application is already codesigned with a valid signature and ***any changes*** are made to the signed contents of it's `.app bundle` it will come back as `invalid`. So to answer your question, changing one byte in a signed apps info.plist will invalidate the signature. Changing an .apps icon does not affect the codesignature nor does adding something else entirely into it's app bundle, strangely enough. Well, maybe not entirely strange — since those actions (presumably) won't be changing/manipulating the signed contents.

As for associating filetypes with your application, that is handled through [LaunchServices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html). If you aren't able to specify the properties at build time (using an info.plist) then you can use a [dynamic configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/000-Introduction/introduction.html) instead.